# What is the best way to separate string using string.format() function or LINQ ?

Tags: c#, string, linq

Is there a way to change "`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP`" to "`ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP`" using `string.format()` function or perhaps LINQ ?
I am using this statement

```
Out= String.Format("{0}-{1}", String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", In.Substring(0, 4), In.Substring(4, 4), In.Substring(8, 4)), In.Substring(12, 4));
```

is there a better and clearer way to accomplish this?

Comment: Problem with your variant is that if the string is shorter than 16 chars, your program will **die!!**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *could* use `string.Format`, but you would still have to use `SubString` to get the different parts.

You should probably just use `Insert`:

```
string result = myString.Insert(12, "-").Insert(8, "-").Insert(4, "-");
```

LINQ is overkill for something like this.

Answer (score 9):

This is really easy to do without LINQ or string.format, so I would suggest using this code instead:

```
string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
for( int i = 4; i < s.Length; i += 5){
  s = s.Insert(i, "-");
}
```

This will insert a dash after each 4 characters (i assumed that is what you wanted).

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, in Linq:

```
string result = input.Select((c, i) => i > 0 && i % 4 == 0 ? "-" + c : c.ToString())
                .Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + s2);
```

Of course, I wouldn't recommand using Linq in this case, as a 'classical' solution would be more efficient AND more readable.

Still, I enjoyed writing this one :D

Comment: Ha ha :D nice 1! i too tried something like this. But did not work out

Comment: It works as expected, but it's problem (as KooKiz also knows even if he posted this solution), for a person not knowing what this code does it's very hard to read and see what it does. I don't see why you want to use LINQ for this just because it's new and shiny. I **love** LINQ, but I don't force it where it's just plain simpler and much more readable to use a good old loop, and another structure that fits the scenario.

Comment: Two more things. Performance wise this does not matter since it's such a small string. It will only matter if it's a really great number of strings you want to "convert". In your question you ask for a better or clearer way. Do you really really see this code as clearer? So it's not an efficient question in this case, but a readability question.

Comment: Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen yes you right it is not a clearer answer. i`m just interested about it`s **inline** solution besides your suggestion plus this suggestion wont gonna be die if the string were shorter than 16 chars. thanks to all

Comment: Rzassar - Mine wont die for a string shorter than 16 chars either ;) (or longer)